# Show icon font on image center on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m trying to do an effect and show a search icon font when the mouse hover my "image1.png".
I already did the effect with jQuery but now I do not see how I can integrate the iconic font with jquery. Has anyone done something like that? Can you give a little help?

```
 <article id="loop-news">
     <span id="testIcon"><I  class = "fa fa-search-plus" >  <!--show just on mouse hover -->
     <img src="image1.png" id="test" />
     <h2>Title </h2>
     <p>My Post</p>
 </article>
```

My css to hide icon font at first:

```
#testIcon>i{display:none;}
```

My jquery to give an opacity effect:

```
 $("#test").hover(function() {
     $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
 }, function() {
     $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
 });
```

Comment: Why do you need jquery for this and not just css?

Comment: To give a nice and smooth fade in image!

Comment: CSS3 transitions can handle that. They actually are smoother than jquery...

Comment: Ah ok I didn´t know that css3 could do the fade effect. I´ll try to find some documentatil about that.Thank you!

Comment: If the answer is what you were looking for, feel free to mark it as correct ;) Otherwise, I'm happy to help any other way!

Comment: Thank you :) It was exactly that that I was trying to do with jQuery but in your example I just have some difficult to center the "<h2>title</h2>" in the center of image, I can do that but with "big values" like margin-right=1400px and things like this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use CSS3 transitions if I understand your issue.  In this example, I would just replace the font-family with your icon font (assuming that's how it works - never used it).

```
h2 {
    position: aboslute;
    margin-top: -350px;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}
#loop-news:hover h2 {
    display: block;
}
#loop-news:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}
img, h2 {
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cP8cA/1/)